# Update dynamic SQL table with history table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I was successful in implementing a table's history (for auditing) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2020371/3717115) that basically suggests to create two tables wherein one contains the current version and the other a table of versions with the real data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Page(  
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,  
    Name nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,  
    CreatedByName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    CurrentRevision int NOT NULL, 
    CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE dbo.PageContent(
    PageID int NOT NULL,
    Revision int NOT NULL,
    Title nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    User nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    LastModified datetime NOT NULL,
    Comment nvarchar(300) NULL,
    Content nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(200) NULL
```

My `UPDATE`s to static, non-dynamic fields are OK where the versioning is recognised correctly (rough pseudocode adapted from dev't code):

```
$sql_pagecontent = array(
    'PageID' => // logic to get PageID
    'Title' => $data['Title']
    'User' => $data['User'],
    'LastModified' => $this->get_date(),
    'Comment' => $data['Comment'],
    'Content' => $data['Content'],
    'Description' => $data['Description']
);

$this->db->insert('PageContent', $sql_pagecontent);
$id_version = $this->db->insert_id();

$sql_page = array(
    'CurrentRevision' => $id_version
);

if($type_version === 'UPDATE')
{
    $this->db->where('ID', $page_id_to_replace);
    $this->db->update('Page', $sql_page);
}
else
{
    $this->db->insert('Page', $sql_page);
}
```

The problem is when I apply this to **dynamic** tables with `UPDATE`.

During `UPDATE`, I want to achieve the following, just similar to the non-dynamic tables (context of `Page` and `PageContent`):

- a new `PageContent` row is `INSERT`ed (new `PageContent`), a new row of `CurrentRevision` in `Page` is added
- a new `PageContent` row is `INSERT`ed (update of existing `PageContent`), the `CurrentRevision` in `Page` `UPDATE`d with this new row
- deleted `PageContent`s are removed from `Page`

**NOTE** I want each row of these dynamic tables preserved in both `Page` and `PageContent` if ever the user wants to check the changes so I just cannot do `INSERT` which will just flood the table.

I cannot seem to filter these dynamic values correctly with the current implementation.

Please advise on how to deal with this use case.

---

**Solution**

I am not sure if my current implementation of my said requirements is correct, feasible or recommended but it does the job:

1. get ID of current `PageContent` being modified
2. get ID of current `Page` being modified
3. **delete all rows of `Page` that has the ID of #1**
4. **perform `INSERT` and apply `UPDATE` as type of action of `PageContent`**

Number 3 is key to make sure whether existing rows are edited/deleted or new rows added are saved as the current version in `Page`. Number 4 puts this into place to make sure every row is recognised.

Comment: Can you please be specific in what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Zeeshan: I want to update my table that contains the **current version** ID of the other dynamic table whether new rows are added, existing rows are edited or existing rows are deleted.