# How to track who changes a record in a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to track who changes to a table in mySQL database. Would you please give me an idea how  I can determine which of my application users makes changes to a record in a table?

Comment: Are you asking how you can determine which *MySQL user* makes changes, or how you can determine which of your *application users* make changes?

Comment: I believe you need to use a Trigger to achieve this. Take a look at a similar question on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547773/how-to-track-changes-in-multiple-columns-in-database-table-for-auditing-purposes)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table with 2 columns that their name is `colmun1` and `column2` You should add `modified_by` column and also add this trigger:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER before_update_sometable
    BEFORE UPDATE ON sometable FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.column1 <> OLD.column1 or NEW.column2 <> OLD.column2) THEN
             NEW.modified_by = user();
        END IF;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: That returns database user. I want the function to return Application users.