# Inserted, Deleted Tables (Magic Tables) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am regular user of MS-SQL but now working on a project which has mysql as a back-end.

Please tell me that is there exists such a inserted/Deleted tables (Magic tables) in mysql which I can use inside trigger or in normal queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called `NEW` and `OLD` in MySQL.

`NEW` is the new record to be inserted or the updated data.

`OLD` is the deleted record, or the old data before an update.

See the documentation for creating a trigger here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: can we use it for normal queries too as we can use inserted/deleted using "output" in MS-SQL Server 2005/2008?

Comment: @Rajesh I looked around and was unable to find an analogous method to the OUTPUT clause in MSSQL.

Comment: @Rajesh, the new/old virtual tables only exist within triggers. You cannot use them in normal queries. You can however save your deleted rows to a table of your choosing inside the trigger.