# Reference a Many-To-Many row

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am dealing with the design of a database in Flask connected to Postgresql. I have 2 Tables `Reservation` and `Device` which are related through a many-to-many relationship Table `ReservationItem` as follows:

```
| Reservation |     | Device |     | ReservationItem |     
| ----------- |     | ------ |     | --------------- |
| id_res      |     | id_dev |     | res_id (FK/PK)  |
| etc...      |     | etc..  |     | dev_id (FK/PK)  |
                                   | created_at      |
                                   | status          |
```

Where `dev_id` and `res_id` are `foreign` keys and make up the composite `primary` key for the table. The columns `created_at` and `status` where originally conceived to track the history of the development of each Reservation-Device status.

**Example**
Someone reserves 3 `Devices` (respectively with `id_dev`'s 1 - 2 - 3)  on the `1st of January 2021` hence I would create 1 `Reservation` entry (`id_res` 1) and 3 `ReservationItem` entry with `status` "booked".

```
ReservationItem
| --------------------------------------|
| res_id | dev_id | created_at | status |
| ------------------------------------- |
|   1    |   1    | 2021-01-01 | booked |
|   1    |   2    | 2021-01-01 | booked |
|   1    |   3    | 2021-01-01 | booked |
```

On the 2nd of January the client returns the `Device.id = 1` so I would create a fourth entry in the `ReservationItem` Table where the only updated fields are `created_at` and `status`, so that I could track where the devices are.

```
| --------------------------------------- |
| res_id | dev_id | created_at | status   |
| --------------------------------------- |
|   1    |   1    | 2021-01-01 | booked   |
|  ...   |  ...   |    ...     |    ...   |
|   1    |   1    | 2021-01-02 | returned |
```

Which basically weaken the uniqueness of the `composite key (res_id,dev_id)`.

So I thought: Should I created another table  lets say `History` to track these updates?

These would be my new models...

```
| ReservationItem |     | History       |   
| --------------- |     | ------------- |   
| id_assoc (PK)   |     | id_hist (PK)  | 
| res_id (FK)     |     | assoc_id (FK) | 
| dev_id (FK)     |     | created_at    | 
|                 |     | status        |
```

I would change the `ReservationItem` Table so that `res_id` are `dev_id` are not primary keys anymore. I would move the `created_at` and `status` into the `History` table and I would add the column `id_assoc` and use it as primary key, so that I can reference it from the `History` table.

I've been looking around and it seems that using one column as primary key in a many to many relationship is not ideal.

How would you design the relationships otherwise?
Is there any tool that Flask offers?

**EDIT**
After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437/how-to-track-data-changes-in-a-database-table), which suggests to audit database table and write logs to track changed entries (or operations on databases) I found [this article](https://sagarkaurav.hashnode.dev/tracking-database-changes-in-flask-sqlalchemy-for-audit-logs) which suggests how to implement audit logs in Flask. But why wouldn't my solution work (or lets say "isn't ideal")?

thank you!

Comment: "it seems that adding a primary key to a many to many relationship is not ideal". First : the primary key is just mandatory for any kind of table in postgres. Second : the primary key can be composite, ie (res_id, dev_id) so no need of the id_assoc column in the table ReservationTime. Third ; your first attempt with 3 tables sounds more optimzed than the second with the History table which doesn't provide any added value in your case.

Comment: I have never heard of a composite primary key. I will take a look into it . Thank you!. About your third point: I was considering the new design because, if you think about it, one entry in the ReservationItem Table can have many "updates" that can be tracked over time (different status steps such as "delivered", "booked", "returned", etc..).  I was wondering if things would get messy without a fourth table...

Comment: The fourth table is a good idea when you need additional columns in table ReservationItem (independent from the History of the association) and additional columns in table History. In the basic example given of your question, the fourth table has no real added value.

Comment: @EdouardH.  ok that is great! meaning that if I want to track who did a change (for example a User registered in another table) - meaning adding a column "user_id" to the "History" table - would you drop the composite primary key and assign an id to each ReservationItem entry?

Comment: both solutions are possible with pros and cons in both cases, either keep id_assoc as primary key of table ReservationItem and assoc_id in table History refering to id_assoc as a foreign key, or remove id_assoc and keep (res_id, dev_id) as composite primary key of table ReservationItem, and (id_res, id_dev) added to table History as a foreign key refering to table ReservationItem (id_res, id_dev)